# Angular 2+ (ngModelChange) on input on itself

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodelchange

I have number input field and I want to restrict it so max value will be 100. So When user types number by number I want it to be restricted in real time. For this I'm using `(ngModelChange)`.

Example:

- User types 1 its OK,
- User types again 1, its OK,
- User types 1 again it will automatically replace 111 with 100, and its OK
- User types 1 again it should be automatically replaced with 100. but it stays 1001 and it will continue adding numbers regarding ngModelChange restriction.

Here is html code:

```
<!-- NOT WORKING -->
<input type="number"
       class="form-control"
       maxlength="3"
       [(ngModel)]="period"
       (ngModelChange)="onValueChange()"
       id="period" placeholder="0" min="0"
       max="100" step="1" name="period">

<!-- WORKING -->
<p>{{period}}</p>
```

It's controller:

```
  public period: number;

  onValueChange() {
     if (this.period > 100) this.period = 100;
  }
```

This will update period but only once. If I continue to type more numbers it wont update the input field. Also `maxlength="3"` is not working

I tried the same concept but on paragraph and it is working. Probably the problem is only on input field.

Comment: Try updating the model value inside settimeout like this: setTimeOut(()=>{  if (this.period > 100) this.period = 100; })

Comment: Can you answer the question so I can Accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since You updating the model value inside ngModelChange the model value is out of sync with view value. try updating the model value asynchronusly inside settimeout.

```
onValueChange() {
    setTimeout(()=>{
      if (this.period > 100) this.period = 100;
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `FormControl` and `validators` instead:

```
<input class="form-control" 
        type="number" 
        min="0" 
        max="100" 
        placeholder="0" 
        [(ngModel)]="period" 
        name="period" 
        [formControl]="period">

this.period= new FormControl("", [Validators.max(100)]);
```

Comment: I want to update it real time, so I think this wont work...

Answer (score 0):

try to use instead `(input)` of `(ngModelChange)` :

```
(input)="onValueChange($event)"
```

in your ts code will be :

```
onValueChange(event): void {
  console.log(event);
  let p = event.target.value;
  if (p > 100) this.period = 100;
}
```

Comment: I get error on $event.target.value --> Unresolved variable value

Comment: check my edited answer but you have to checkout your console log if the event caught correctly and contains the value

Comment: Ahh this will works only once, I can continue typing numbers after third time and it will add again 1001111. I have to refocus and start typing again and it will reset it but only once....